# MySQL not using primary key on inner join

Tags: mysql, join, primary-key

I have two tables:
Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE `lk_transaction_types` (
  `transactionTypeID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `isActive` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `isInbound` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `isOutbound` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`transactionTypeID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE `ediLoad` (
  `loadID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `processID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `success` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `transactionTypeID` tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `escoID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ldcID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `commodityType` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `filename` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `loadDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `processed` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `processedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dataApplied` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `dataAppliedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `errorID` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `error` tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `warning` tinyint(2) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`loadID`),
  KEY `idx_processID` (`processID`,`transactionTypeID`,`escoID`),
  KEY `idx_escoID` (`escoID`),
  KEY `idx_filename` (`success`,`filename`),
  KEY `idx_bulk` (`processed`,`loadDate`),
  KEY `idx_loadDate` (`loadDate`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35086005 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When trying to run a simple query it is not using the Primary Key on the lk_transaction_types table:

```
SELECT COUNT(0)
FROM edi.ediLoad l
INNER JOIN edi.lk_transaction_types lk 
  ON  lk.transactionTypeID = l.transactionTypeID
WHERE l.escoID = 2
AND lk.isActive = 1
AND lk.isInbound = 1;
```

The Query is very slow. So I run explain

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(0)
FROM edi.ediLoad l
INNER JOIN edi.lk_transaction_types lk 
  ON  lk.transactionTypeID = l.transactionTypeID
WHERE l.escoID = 2
AND lk.isActive = 1
AND lk.isInbound = 1;
```

This returns

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  lk  NULL    ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    31  3.23    Using where
1   SIMPLE  l   NULL    ref idx_escoID  idx_escoID  5   const   71580   10.00   Using where
```

This seems like a simple query with one join on a primary key. Why is it not using the primary key? I've even tried adding 'FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (PRIMARY)' to the join and it still doesn't use the primary key. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Even though _conceptually_ the WHERE is processed after the join, MySQL tries to reduce the number of rows joined by checking against relevant criteria in the WHERE first. Since `ediLoad` does not have an index starting with `transactionTypeID`, and is the large table; it is likely ignoring the relatively unhelpful pk of `edi`.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a little on what @Uueerdo is saying in the comment above: MySQL can't use the *idx_processID* index in this case since *transactionTypeID* is the second column in the index, and the first colum (*processID*) is not part of the where statement.

If you add a new key with *transactionTypeID* only, it will be used.

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html:

> MySQL can use multiple-column indexes for queries that test all the
>   columns in the index, or queries that test just the first column, the
>   first two columns, the first three columns, and so on. If you specify
>   the columns in the right order in the index definition, a single
>   composite index can speed up several kinds of queries on the same
>   table.

Comment: Adding the key speeds up the query but just by filtering ediLoad. It still doesn't use the PK for the join

Comment: @MichaelShapiro: The datatype for ediLoad.transactionTypeID is tinyint(2) while in lk_transaction_types it is int(10), which I assume is the problem. Make them equal (presumably both int(10)) and I reckon you should be ok.